# php code drupal database get

Tags: php, json, drupal-7

Ok I am using drupal 7.
I need to get information out of some tables so I can read them in a iPhone app.  I found out I need a php code to convert a table to json format. I need the code to go to a database "x" then to table "y".  Then list entity_id and name from all the fields. This will be a read only. I don't know the first thing about php code. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps :-

1. Learns PHP :-)
2. learn how drupal works
3. [Learn Drupal hooks](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7)
4. [Drupal query](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database).

Once you are inside drupal you dont need to coonect to drupal database, its handled by Drupal.

After this you can use [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and in call back function you can return required JSON output.
Use that link in your application.

Chheers!!!